# Redirecting old domain that was on HTTPS to new domain on HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I am trying to point an old domain that was secure through HTTPs to my new domain. I was instructed to add an `.htaccess` file to my old domains folder (which is empty other than cgi-bin, error_log and the new .htaccess file).

Here is what is in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The `https://olddomain` does not redirect to `https://newdomain.com`

Comment: Do you have ssl cert for the old domain?

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration redirect everything `^(.*)$` to the same domain `%{HTTP_HOST}`, what you want is to redirect it to the new one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that your `.htaccess` file is being read (the fastest way is to add some garbage to it, an error 500 should pop up in your browser).

Second, I would try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```